# Looking for something like cl-applicable-method-p

Tags: common-lisp, eieio

I am looking for something that could be used like this:

```
(when (cl-applicable-method-p 'foo "arg") ...)
```

I vaguely remember that I have seen that once and that it came with a comment saying that one shouldn't use it. However I would like to at least investigate this approach, which I cannot do if I cannot guess the name and am unable to find the implementation. (But please let me know what is wrong with using such a predicate, if anything.)

I cannot just call the generic function and prepare to handle `cl-no-applicable-method` errors or use a no-op default-method because I have to do some additional work before and after calling the generic function, but only if it actually is implemented given the arguments I intend to call it with

Actually the "argument" is the current major-mode, the arglist of the methods is `(&context (major-mode MODE))`, which probably complicates this further.

It would be nice if I could do something like:

```
(when (cl-applicable-method-p 'foo &context major-mode)
  (prepare)
  (foo)
  (finish))
```

Another approach would be:

```
(defmacro foo-common (&rest body)
  `(progn (prepare)
          ,@body
          (finish)))

(cl-defgeneric foo ()
  nil) ; noop

(cl-defmethod foo (&context (major-mode emacs-lisp-mode))
  (foo-common
   (mode-specific-stuff)))
```

but that feels hackish, it would be nicer if `foo-common` could be replaced with a `foo` `:around` method.

---

I am trying to replace the various `magit-...-refresh-buffer` functions used in [`magit-refresh-buffer`](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/magit-mode.el#L1063-L1102) with a generic function.

Comment: I think the closest I can think of is `cl-next-method-p`, but I'd indeed recommend to stay away from it.  Maybe we could suggest a better solution if you explained what you're hoping to gain from the use of a generic-function for `magit-refresh-buffer`?

Comment: I don't particularly like `(funcall (intern (concat ... "-refresh-buffer")))` and I hope for other small benefits. Nothing major, just consistency with other changes where using a generic function poses no problems.

Comment: What I am mostly interested in is to learn *why* I shouldn't do this. Is it un-clos-y to ask "does this exist?" instead of calling the function and see what happens, or does the reason have more to do with implementation details?

Comment: One way to look at the problem is that the code that signals "no such method" is basically itself a default method, and if you check for existence of a method you might find a "spurious" method (e.g. there's a `:before` method but no primary method, or there's a dummy default method which just signals some other error).  In addition,  I actively discourage use of `cl-next-method-p` because its implementation is horribly hackish and brittle (but implementing it in a robust way would be a lot more expensive for a feature that's basically never used but would cost even when you don't use it).